# tinyscrollbar jquery plugin bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use tinyscrollbar for jQuery. It works well, but when I upgrade my container and I upgrade the scroll, it always puts me into the beginning of the container. I tried 'relative' option, but it's the same.

Here's the source: http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

I removed the *else* statement in the line: `iScroll = (sScroll == 'relative' && oContent.ratio <= 1) ...` so it doesn't get `0`, but the problem is with using the mousewheel, it doesn't scroll back to down.

It seems the bug is right here, but I can't find it.

```
function wheel(oEvent){
    if(!(oContent.ratio >= 1)){
        oEvent = $.event.fix(oEvent || window.event);
        var iDelta = oEvent.wheelDelta ? oEvent.wheelDelta/120 : -oEvent.detail/3;
        iScroll -= iDelta * options.wheel;
        iScroll = Math.min((oContent[options.axis] - oViewport[options.axis]), Math.max(0, iScroll));

        oThumb.obj.css(sDirection, iScroll / oScrollbar.ratio);
        oContent.obj.css(sDirection, -iScroll);
        oEvent.preventDefault();
    };
```

BTW: Also if you know a different custom scrollbar component (with images) that works on IE6+, tell me.

Comment: Creating a [jsFiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/dtVDu/), everything seems to work properly for me; the mousewheel works fine before and after adding content.  Can you confirm if this works correctly for you?

Comment: your javascript code in the fiddle is not correct. The current version of tinyscrollbar cant be chained so your update method isn't working.       

Change the following line.

var s = $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();

in 

var s = $('#scrollbar1');
s.tinyscrollbar();

Answer (score 0):

When you add content and you trigger the update method. it will always default to top..

However you can add the parameter "bottom" or "relative" to the method. And it will behave accordingly.

Relative means the thumb will stay relativily in the same place even when the new contents size is different then the old one.

Comment: It movest to top when I use 'relative' on IE6.

Comment: the examples on baijs.nl work fine in ie6.. so you must be doing something wrong in your css. Put op a demo of what you are tring to do.